# Why are my contents in my webpage overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am an amateur at coding and I am trying to code for my own website. Why my contents are overlapping? How do I make it in such a way that my content in section-1 is below the content in slide-show-container?

The following picture is the problem I am experiencing at the moment:
[image]

The following picture is how I want it to look like:
[image]

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 7000); // Change image every 7 seconds
  }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.mySlides {display: none;}

.slideshow-container img {vertical-align: middle;
height:500px;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin:  2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C5B358;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}

.slideshow-container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3150%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 
 .slideshow-container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4650%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow-container .btn:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 

 .slideshow-container .btn3:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 
 

 .section-1 h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100; 
  text-align: center;
 }

 .section-1 p{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/ A.png" style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">SCHEDULE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/B.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">BROWSE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/C.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn3">SHOP</button>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section-1">
      <h1>AAA AAA AAAAAAA AAAA<br>AA A AAAAA AAAA</h1>
      <p>AAAAAAA AA AAA AAAAAA AAAAA, AAAAA AA AAAAA A AAAAA AA AAA AAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAA AA AA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AA AAAAAAAAA, AAA AA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAAAA AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAAAA AAAA AAAA AAAAAA AAAAAAA AAA? <Br>AAAAAAA AA AAA AA AAAA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAA AAAAA. </p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Remove `height: 10px;` from `.slideshow-container`

Answer (score 1):

You can set a `min-height:` to your `slideshow-container`,if you initially want some `height`. You content is more than the `height` and it is `overflow` on the `.slideshow-container`. Try this :)

```
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 10px;// Change to min-height
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}
```

**FULL CODE:**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.mySlides {display: none;}

.slideshow-container img {vertical-align: middle;
height:500px;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 10px;/*min-height used*/
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin:  2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C5B358;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}

.slideshow-container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3150%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 
 .slideshow-container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4650%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow-container .btn:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 

 .slideshow-container .btn3:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 
 

 .section-1 h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100; 
  text-align: center;
 }

 .section-1 p{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/ A.png" style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">SCHEDULE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/B.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">BROWSE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/C.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn3">SHOP</button>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section-1">
      <h1>AAA AAA AAAAAAA AAAA<br>AA A AAAAA AAAA</h1>
      <p>AAAAAAA AA AAA AAAAAA AAAAA, AAAAA AA AAAAA A AAAAA AA AAA AAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAA AA AA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AA AAAAAAAAA, AAA AA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAAAA AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAAAA AAAA AAAA AAAAAA AAAAAAA AAA? <Br>AAAAAAA AA AAA AA AAAA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAA AAAAA. </p>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Right! The height of .slideshow-container is a problem here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slide</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    * {box-sizing: border-box;}
.mySlides {display: none;}

.slideshow-container img {vertical-align: middle;
height:500px;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  /*height: 10px;*/
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin:  2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C5B358;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}

.slideshow-container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3150%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 
 .slideshow-container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4650%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow-container .btn:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 

 .slideshow-container .btn3:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 
 

 .section-1 h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100; 
  text-align: center;
 }

 .section-1 p{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
 }
</style>
<body>
<div class="main">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/ A.png" style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">SCHEDULE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/B.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">BROWSE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/C.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn3">SHOP</button>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section-1">
      <h1>AAA AAA AAAAAAA AAAA<br>AA A AAAAA AAAA</h1>
      <p>AAAAAAA AA AAA AAAAAA AAAAA, AAAAA AA AAAAA A AAAAA AA AAA AAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAA AA AA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AA AAAAAAAAA, AAA AA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAAAA AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAAAA AAAA AAAA AAAAAA AAAAAAA AAA? <Br>AAAAAAA AA AAA AA AAAA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAA AAAAA. </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 7000); // Change image every 7 seconds
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have commented and changes the line that you have to change the min-height attribute

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
  showSlides();

  function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 7000); // Change image every 7 seconds
  }
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.mySlides {display: none;}

.slideshow-container img {vertical-align: middle;
height:500px;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-height: 10px;//changed here
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 7px;
  width: 7px;
  margin:  2px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #C5B358;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}

.slideshow-container .btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3150%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 
 .slideshow-container .btn3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4650%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding:6px 12px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow-container .btn:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 

 .slideshow-container .btn3:hover {
  color:#C5B358;
 } 
 .section-1{
 display:block;
 position:relative;
 } 

 .section-1 h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: 100; 
  text-align: center;
  margin:10px;
 }

 .section-1 p{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="main">

    <div class="slideshow-container">

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/ A.png" style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">SCHEDULE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/B.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn">BROWSE</button>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <img src="file:///User/Name/Desktop/C.png"style="width:100%">
        <button class="btn3">SHOP</button>
      </div>

      <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span> 
        <span class="dot"></span>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="section-1">
      <h1>AAA AAA AAAAAAA AAAA<br>AA A AAAAA AAAA</h1>
      <p>AAAAAAA AA AAA AAAAAA AAAAA, AAAAA AA AAAAA A AAAAA AA AAA AAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAA AA AA AAAAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAAAA AA AAAAAAAAA, AAA AA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAAAA AAA AAAAAAAA AAAAA.<br>AAAAA AAAA AAAA AAAAAA AAAAAAA AAA? <Br>AAAAAAA AA AAA AA AAAA AAAAA AAA AAA AAAA AAAAA. </p>
    </div>

  </div>
```